# Custom spinner using TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView for Country,State and District

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

1. I am working on multiple Custom Spinner using  TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView and i want to select data accourding to above spinner validate in parrallel thread like when i select country then change the data state and district
2. Using Retrofit , Kotlin
3. And also using the custom Adapter class
4. Please help me Thanks In Advance.

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/selectMeterTypeLayout"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:hint="@string/select_meter_type">

                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/selectMeterType"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="none" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I think so you need to call api for every spinner. In use different adapter class for spinners and show that in UI

Comment: Can you explain your issue?  what exactly you’re facing?

Comment: Actually MY issues in CustomAdapter and handle the spinner in parallel in like in AsyncTask using  new AsyncDivision().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,Query)